# Can only run python code from separate tesseract console

Tags: python, visual-studio, opencv, tesseract

I'm using visual studio to write my project and wanted to use `pytesseract` for image recognition so I installed it with pip. Then figured I had to download tesseract too so I did and it's available at a separate folder with a 'console' command line. The problem is that if I try running my code in visual studio it says tesseract wasn't found.

But it works fine if I run the script through tesseract's command line. Is there a more convenient way to execute my code? It seems a bit tedious to always run it from the separate command line.

Comment: Are you working on windows or Linux system? Did you add tesseract's executable to your PATH?

Comment: I'm on windows and unfortunately I not familiar with adding to PATH. Should I try adding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add tesseract folder to system PATH. It should fix problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just read [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/):

```
# If you don't have tesseract executable in your PATH, include the following:
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try to be more thorough with reading documentation in the future.